# Python DDL abstraction

Tags: python, ddl

Are there any Python libraries that provide an abstraction of [SQL DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language)?
I have an application that needs to dynamically add/adjust database columns, and I don't want to have to model CREATE TABLE and all the datatypes.

I am looking for something relatively lightweight; full [ORMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) like [SQLAlchemy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLAlchemy) will unfortunately not be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at SQLAlchemy?
It's an object-relational mapper (abstraction layer) that sits between your python code and the (relational) database.
It does DDL such as create table.